# Who played the second evil motorcyclist in A-ha's "Take On Me" video?

Tags: actors, actor-identification, music-video, take-on-me

In the A-ha music video “Take On Me” who was the actor that portrayed the second evil motorcyclist? (The one with the 13 helmet who gets punched by Morten Harket)

I understand the first one was played by Phillip Jackson, but what about the other guy? I have a photo of him, but I still don’t know his name.

In this picture, he’s the one on the viewers’ right:

[image: The older one standing next to Bunty Bailey]

Comment: https://m.imdb.com/title/tt4645418/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_ttfc_2

Comment: @closevoters This is definitely on-topic. Briefly looking through the video, there’s a scene with a comic book’s panels moving and a hand popping out of it, among other things.

Comment: Here's what I saw on SE Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238920/stack-exchange-for-popular-music-and-music-videos

Comment: @Shreedhar watch the video...it’s a story with very clear science fiction/fantasy elements.

Comment: IMDb unfortunately doesn’t list his name, are there any other places I could possibly find out?

Answer (score 10):

[IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4645418/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_ttfc_2) now lists him as [Alfie Curtis](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0193238/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cl3).

[image: Alfie Curtis' portrait from his IMDB Page][image: Cropped close up of the character in question]

The nose and eyes make the resemblance unmistakable.

Comment: He played the guy in the Star Wars Cantina bar scene who says, "He doesn't like you. I don't like you either!"